# How can I create Join table in MySQL database using hibernate in Java?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entity table called appointment and service. One appointment can be many services. Services already store in the database. We can newly add appointment. When add new appointment we selected added services from the drop down menu. Can add many services with one appointment. I need to store new record on appointment table and store relevant appointment id and services id's on another join table. Here attached image with my problem.

[image]

Already I tried many ways for do this. Bellow is one attempt.

Here is appointment class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appointment")
public class Appointment extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "service_x_appointment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "beautyservice_id"))
    Set<BeautyService> beautyServices;

    private String type;
    private Date date;
    private String time;
    private String description;
    private int approval;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private User user;

    //getter and setter

}
```

Here is BeautyService class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="beauty_service")
public class BeautyService extends AbstractPersistable<Long>  {


    private String serviceName;
    private String timeDuration;
    private String amount;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Here is appointment controller class code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createAppointment",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAppointment(@RequestBody Appointment appointment){

        String response = null;
        response = appointmentService.save(appointment);
        return response;
    }
```

Here is appointment service class code

```
public String save(Appointment appointment) {
        appoinmentRepository.save(appointment);
        return "Appointment added successfully";
    }
```

Here is the my request body.

```
{   
    "type":"Type02",
    "date":null,
    "time":"20:56",
    "description":"Hellow World",
    "approval":0,
    "user":{
        "id":2,
        "name" : "Alex",
        "telephone" : "0774466886",
        "age":21,
        "email": null
    },

    "beautyServices" : [

        {   
            "id":1,
            "serviceName":"hair strate",
            "timeDuration" : "02 Hours",
            "amount" : 5000
        },
        {   
            "id":2,
            "serviceName":"Eye brows",
            "timeDuration" : "02 Hours",
            "amount" : 5000
        },
        {

            "id":3,
            "serviceName":"Near cutting",
            "timeDuration" : "02 Hours",
            "amount" : 5000
        }
        ]

}
```

Why not record in the join table? Only appointment table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways. One has been specified @Aritra Paul, which is actually `Bidirectional` representation of `OneToMany` mapping. 
I think you want to use `UniDirectional` representation. In that case you won't have to use `mappedBy`.

Just create your entities like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appointment", schema="ADMIN")
public class Appointment implements Serializable {


     @OneToMany
     @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id")
     @JoinTable(name = "service_appointment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"))
     Set<Service> services;
}


@Entity
public class Service {
       // Some Properties. No need to specify reference of Appointment here.

}
```

If you define your entities like that you will have a join table like this

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| appointment_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| service_id     | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: what is the base entity extends by Service. Is that compulsory. How ever I tried different ways. When I add appointment, Then appointment table update successfully. But Join table not updated. What is the problem.I update my question with postman request.

Comment: @QOnly Added Base Entity by mistake. updated the answer.

Comment: I did like you, But my join table not updated. Is there wrong with my request body. Kindly help me

Comment: I updated my Question.Join table created like you. But not add record in that join table.Please look it,

Comment: Did you set services in appointment object while saving? Please add java code you are using to save appointment.

Comment: Can you check, if appointment object has services set into it, Maybe in debugger mode ?

Comment: Get them added to your appointment object and you will have entries saved into join table then :)

Comment: Is there any problem with my request body. Do u have any idea please.

Comment: Appointment class has `beautyServices` as the reference name. while your json has `service`. i.e why its not getting binded automatically.

Comment: in my real request body its beautyServices but not work.I cant understand. Is there any problem with my beautyServices  array.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the json. I also tried it on some dummy request. It was working. Is `user` object getting bind?

Comment: Yes user object is fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185689/discussion-between-richa-and-qonly).

Comment: @Richa there is some issue. According to this method service id be unique. Then we cannot add the same services. Error show joine table has a unique key.Can you change your post.Thank you.

Comment: @Dev4World. Sorry,I did not get you. I know service Id is unique. The service won't be created again.

Comment: @QOnly: How were you able to solve the issue where services were not getting bound?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't create Joined table entity as you mentioned as it's more the underlying database representation than the object oriented one.

You can achieve the join table by defining something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appointment", schema="ADMIN")
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
//...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="appointment")
@JoinTable(name="Join_Table")
Set <ServiceT> service;
```

use relation mapping ManyToOne or OneToMany according to your table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="service", schema="ADMIN")
public class ServiceT implements Serializable {
//...

@ManyToOne
Appointment appointment;
```

If you want to explicitely set your column name you can use

> @JoinColumn

annotation.

Comment: thanks your answer. But my appointment have many services. Is your answer correct with that scenario. Please update if it is wrong.Bcz im new commer for hibernate.

Comment: If you have multiple service object in appointment then use @OneToMany and vice versa. I have updated my answer

Comment: is correct mappedBy with @ManyToOne? in ServiceT class

Comment: I updated my question. Please you can can give me solution.Thank you.

Comment: Yes.But I cant use mappedBy with MantToOne in ServiceT class

Comment: @Aritraa Paul Please help solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the `beautyServices` are actually being bound from the @RequestBody properly.

The property name is `beautyServices` while in Json it says `"service"`.
In the Json it should say `"beautyServices"` instead of `"service"`.

Also, check if the ids 1, 2, 3 already pre-exists on the beautyServices table. 
If Not, if you want those to get inserted as well by saving appointment, you need to add `CASCADETYPE.PERSIST`.

Comment: My request is ok. I did this according to Richa answer. But now it's show "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'UK_cia8m8iqvdfqmt1sjpajvrcia'" this. What is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that id 3 is already persisted in db, change your request to persist a different id next time.

Comment: According to my question there can be many services for appointment. Then each appointment can be same service id.

Comment: yes, but there can not be more than one service with the same id in service table.
BTW, have you added cascadeType in beautyServices ?

Comment: Yes. Beuty service doesn't has any dublicate ids. I said only jointable can be dublicate values. Different appointment id can be same services in jointable.